# node-gyp rebuild fails when installing webpack and other packages on OSX

Tags: node.js, macos, npm, node-gyp

I'm on OS 10.10.13, with node v0.12.4 and npm v2.10.1. Whenever I run the following command to install webpack `npm install webpack --save-dev --save-exact`, I get the following error when `node-gyp rebuild` is called:

```
> fsevents@0.3.6 install /Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/ev_blurbs/Sites/products/react-week/new-app/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/watchpack/node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents
> node-gyp rebuild

  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/.node
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/.node: Finished
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/fse/fsevents.o
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'HD/Users/ev_blurbs/.node-gyp/0.12.4/src'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'HD/Users/ev_blurbs/.node-gyp/0.12.4/deps/uv/include'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'HD/Users/ev_blurbs/.node-gyp/0.12.4/deps/v8/include'
make: *** [Release/obj.target/fse/fsevents.o] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:269:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1074:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 14.3.0
gyp ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/ev_blurbs/Sites/products/react-week/new-app/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/watchpack/node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents
gyp ERR! node -v v0.12.4
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v1.0.3
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing fsevents@0.3.6
```

The `no such file or directory` errors appear to be looking in the wrong place. For example it is checking for:

`HD/Users/ev_blurbs/.node-gyp/0.12.4/src`

That file is instead located at:

`/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/ev_blurbs/.node-gyp/0.12.4/src`

I used homebrew to install node, and recently updated node, npm, and homebrew. Let me know if you notice any potential problems. Thanks for your help in advance!

Cheers,
Evan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-gyp/issues/65) with `gyp`/`node-gyp` that affects all platforms. You might want to add your two cents to that issue.

Comment: Thanks! Glad I'm not the only one experiencing it.

Comment: It seems like the issue is still there, not fix yet.

Answer (score 2):

node-gyp is a pain on windows and doesn't look like it is going away anytime soon.
My advice to you after a long struggle - If you have the option to develop on a mac or a Linux machine, go for it. However - if you absolutely got to develop on Windows - invest some time setting up a vagrant workflow. or if you're up to the task - go with Docker. I chose vagrant for my windows setup exactly for this reason. to avoid the node-gyp nightmare...
Vagrant is basically a way to automate provisioning of a VM running Linux and run an environment close as possible to the production configuration.
One of its features is to Sync folders between the hosting OS - Windows in this case, and the Linux VM. What this gives you is the ability to use your favorite editor and anything else on windows as a dev machine, while your code and npm installs actually runs on a Linux VM. from them on - you can use node-gyp.
Hope this helps.